# SDL together with WSL

Tags: c++, sdl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glm-math

I am trying to start a c++ program that simply opens up a blue window.
I have tried both xMing and vcxsrv and exported display to 0 but when I run my program nothing happens.

If I run xeyes the eyes show and follow my cursor as expected.

My question is does anyone know how to get a program with SDL to open a window using WSL? Why does it work with xeyes but nothing happens with selfcreated code?

The code works on a regular linux machine.

EDIT:
here is the code. I figured out the program shuts down directly, if I enter a cin at the end I see the blue window but I am not sure why it shuts down directly?

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "SDLauxiliary.h"

using namespace std;
using glm::vec3;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
SDL_Surface* screen;

void Draw();

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
screen = InitializeSDL( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
while( NoQuitMessageSDL() )
{
    Draw();
}
SDL_SaveBMP( screen, "screenshot.bmp" );
int a = 0;
cin >> a;
return 0;
}

void Draw()
{

for( int y=0; y<SCREEN_HEIGHT; ++y )
{

    for( int x=0; x<SCREEN_WIDTH; ++x )
    {
        vec3 color(0,0,1);
        PutPixelSDL( screen, x, y, color );
    }
}

if( SDL_MUSTLOCK(screen) )
    SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);

SDL_UpdateRect( screen, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code so we can have a look at it? Also, are you sure that you checked for all possible errors returned by SDL?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: Does SDL works on WSL ?

Comment: Which version of SDL are you using?

Comment: I guess, what you could do is compile it to a .exe file (instead of a file without an file extension). And then, you could open file explorer and enter \\wsl$. This brings you to the wsl directories. Now just go through it and find the executable, and run it from windows, not wsl.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're doing something along the lines of https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx in order to use an X server to render inside WSL and view it on the Windows host.

Depending on your SDL version, this may be possible in theory but I'd guess you'll need to very carefully instruct it *not* to use the "hardware" (whatever that means for WSL). You might have better luck asking the experts in `#SDL` over https://webchat.freenode.net/

In the meantime, you can use the following (assuming SDL2) to at least get a few diagnostics.

```
SDL_version linked;
SDL_GetVersion(&linked);
SDL_version compiled;
SDL_VERSION(&compiled);
std::cout << "Compiled with v."  << SDL_VERSIONNUM(compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch)
           << ", linking with v." << SDL_VERSIONNUM(linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch)
           << "\n";

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
{
  cout << "SDL failed to init: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
  exit(1);
}
```

I'll also point out the obvious, which is that SDL *does* work natively on Windows, so, although this approach is a fun academic exercise (that's how I got here!) and may have value for programs that can *only* run under Linux for one reason or another...if your end goal is to draw some stuff on the screen, you'll have an easier time doing that.